# Using distGeo with two sets of coordinates

Tags: r, geospatial

I have two sets of coordinates (loc and stat) both in the following format

```
         x         y
1 49.68375  8.978462
2 49.99174  8.238287
3 51.30842 12.411870
4 50.70487  6.627252
5 50.70487  6.627252
6 50.37381  8.040766
```

For each location in the first data set (location of observation) I want to know the location in the second data set (weather stations), that is closest to it. Basically matching the locations of observations to the closest weather station for later analysis of weather effects.

I tried using the distGeo function simply by putting in

```
distGeo(loc, stat, a=6378137, f=1/298.257223563)
```

But that didn't work, because loc and stat are not in the right format.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
outer(seq_len(nrow(loc)), seq_len(nrow(stat)),
      function(a,b) geosphere::distGeo(loc[a,], stat[b,]))
#           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]      [,6]
# [1,]      0.00  88604.79 419299.1 283370.9 283370.9 128560.08
# [2,]  88604.79      0.00 483632.9 194784.6 194784.6  47435.65
# [3,] 419299.12 483632.85      0.0 643230.3 643230.3 494205.86
# [4,] 283370.91 194784.62 643230.3      0.0      0.0 160540.63
# [5,] 283370.91 194784.62 643230.3      0.0      0.0 160540.63
# [6,] 128560.08  47435.65 494205.9 160540.6 160540.6      0.00
```

Brief explanation:

- `outer(1:3, 1:4, ...)` produces two vectors that are a cartesian product, very similar to

  ```r
  expand.grid(1:3, 1:4)
  #    Var1 Var2
  # 1     1    1
  # 2     2    1
  # 3     3    1
  # 4     1    2
  # 5     2    2
  # 6     3    2
  # 7     1    3
  # 8     2    3
  # 9     3    3
  # 10    1    4
  # 11    2    4
  # 12    3    4
  ```

  (using `expand.grid` only for demonstration of the expansion)
- the anonymous function I defined (`function(a,b)...`) is called *once*, where `a` is assigned the integer vector `c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)` (using my `1:3` and `1:4` example), and `b` is assigned the int vector `c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)`.
- within the anon func, `loc[a,]` results in a much longer frame: if `loc` has `m` rows and `stat` has `n` rows, then `loc[a,]` should have `m*n` rows; similarly `stat[b,]` should have `m*n` rows as well. This works well, because `distGeo` (and other `dist*` functions in `geosphere::`) operates in one of two ways:

  - If either of the arguments have 1 row, then its distance is calculated against all rows of the other argument. Unfortunately, unless you know that `loc` or `stat` will always have just one row, this method doesn't work.
  - otherwise, both arguments must have the same number of rows, where the distance is calculated piecewise (1st row of 1st arg with 1st row of 2nd arg; 2nd row 1st arg with 2nd row 2nd arg; etc). This is the method we're prepared for.
- in general, the anon func given to `outer` must deal with vectorized arguments on its own. For instance, if you needed `geoDist` to be called once for each pair (so it would be called `m*n` times), then you have to handle that yourself, `outer` will not do it for you. There are constructs in R that support this (e.g., `mapply`, `Map`) or replace `outer` (`Map`, `expand.grid`, and `do.call`), but that's for another question.